# In opencart how to display products from particular category in all the pages

Tags: opencart

Like displaying latest,special module at content bottom position in all the pages i need to display products from particular category in all pages.Is it possible to display 4 products added in a particular category at content bottom position in all the pages.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need to create a new module for that. Otherwise if you're not using the featured module, you can use that for this requirement.

Comment: Already i am using Featured module in my home page.So i cant use it here.I need to display the products from a particular category in all my pages at content bottom.can i get any free module or else how to write the code to get this.@ Sankar V

Comment: I don't know about any free module. You need to google it. If not available, copy the featured module and modify it for your requirements. Add a condition for your category in the product selection sql query.

Comment: I have already searched for module but i can't find any.As i am a beginner in opencart i am not able to write my own code by editing featured module.can u send the step by step procedure to perform this.. @ Sankar V

Comment: It's easier than you think. You've been working in opencart for over a month now. You need to try yourself. More requirements will come and no one is going to write code for you for all those requirements. First of all you copy `featured` module for your new module and make it working, then add a simple `WHERE` condition. That's all.